# How to add scheduled jobs in domain driven design

Tags: domain-driven-design, scheduler

Which layer I should add scheduler project in domain driven design architecture?

I am thinking of adding scheduler in Distributed service layer and business login inside application services layer.

Here is the solution design I am thinking of:

- Presentation Layer

  - UI project
- Distribute Service Layer

  - Application API
  - Scheduler
- Application Layer

  - Application (Application services for Application API and Scheduler logic)
  - DTO
- Domain Entity Model

  - Project Domain (Domain entities specific to project)
  - Scheduler Domain (Domain entities specific to scheduler)
- Data Persistence

  - Data Access Project (Repositories)
  - Data Access Scheduler Domain (Repositories)
- Cross Cutting Infra.

  - Authorization
  - Logging

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I saw your post I had the simlar kind of requirement why are you creating a seperate domain project for scheduler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since now I've implemented this kind of component in the `Presentation layer`, on the same level as the `UI`. These components are awaken by cronjobs at regular times then they call `Application services` in order to send commands to the `Aggregates`. Then, the `Aggregates`, if necessary and allowed, perform the changes to the system state.

Comment: thank you Constantin for your reply. In my project I am dealing with two different databases - one is main database (application specific) and another for Scheduler. So my question is can we have two domain models project (one for application DB and another for Scheduler ) which will have their own data persistence project. Is it good practice?                                                                                          Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Also I read in another post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912823/which-layer-should-scheduled-task-be-put), scheduler can be implemented in separate infrastructure project and later can be added as external entities. Which one is good practice?

Comment: I've read it, it gives the same answer as me. Maybe you have other question, like how to organize projects because here you asked this "Which layer I should add scheduler project in domain driven design architecture?" and my answer is: "In the Presentation layer"

Comment: Thanks you so much Constantin.

Comment: I had the same question, and was thinking to put it in Application layer,.. However, it makes sense, as cronjob is practiaclly "automated user", which regularly invokes some actions in application... also, the same action probably should be invokable by real user manually.